# J2ME error - the method nextInt() in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java, java-me, random

I just started to learn J2ME and right from the bat I got this error when using Random class. Arg, it's so frustrating. Anyone got the same problem before? I already tried to restart Eclipse, write only the code for the random generator to isolate it but to no avail.
I'm using CLDC 1.1 and MIDP 2.1 by the way.

Comment: Could you copy a piece of your code and the complete error message, please?

Comment: i got error for all lines similar to int R = random.nextInt(256) with random as the static random generator. The error that I got was: the method nextInt() in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are pointing out the wrong CLDC and MIDP libraries. [new Random().nextInt(x)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) exists in CLDC 1.1.

If you are using CLDC 1.0 you can create your own implementation of nextInt(int):

```
public static int random(Random r, int n) {

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)r.nextInt()) >> 31);

    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = r.nextInt();
        val = bits % n;
    } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);

    return val;
}
```

(Same implementation as nextInt(int) in the CLDC 1.1.)

Comment: I'm sure that I specified CLDC 1.1 though

Comment: I bet you have accidentally specified CLDC 1.0, as [that `Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.0/jsr030/java/util/Random.html) is missing the `Random.nextInt(int)` method.

Comment: Yepp @aioobe, I know, it must be it... but clearly he has checked it?!

Comment: I'd suggest that he double check and triple check. It's the only reasonable explanation.

Comment: hm...lemme try to create new project with CLDL 1.1. I hope it's not Eclipse problems.

Answer (score 1):

- nextInt(int) is only available since CLDC 1.1, so you have to specify CLDC 1.1 instead of 1.0
- if you specified cldc 1.1 an still get this error its most likely an error of eclipse. took me hours to find: 
  in Eclipse go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java ME -> Device Management -> choose your Default Device -> Edit -> Libraries -> There you have to remove the cldc_1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in netbeans, and solved it.

1. Right click on your project, go to properties.
2. Go To Libraries & Resources under build
3. Add Library
4. scroll for JMUnit for CLDC11
5. click OK
   and build. all problems solved.

I just left JMUnit for CLDC11 there. not really sure if I need it. maybe I'll test without it once I have made up for lost time.